# Vertical line in CSS-selector?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

In the debugger of Google Chrome *46.0.2490.80 m* I found some interesting css-selector for `svg`:

```
html|* > svg { /* css stuff */ }
```

(`user agent stylesheet`)

As I got it, this selects all `svg` elements, which are `direct children` of … what (`html|*`)? What does this vertical line mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It separates the namespace from the selector.  In this case, it's looking for all svg elements that are direct children of another tag, in the html namespace.

Comment: If you're looking for "all svg elements that are direct children of an html tag", why not do `html > svg` ?

Comment: @ChrisSmith You changed what I said.  I said "... direct children of another tag in the html namespace", which is very different from "direct children of an html tag", assuming by "html tag" you mean THE tag with name "html", and not any tag that is part of the html specification.  `html > svg` is will do the former, while `html|* > svg` will do the latter.

Comment: If all you have is a simple html document (not xhtml), and aren't using things like svg, or objects, etc. then every tag in your document is part of the html namepsace, so `html|* > svg` will act the same as `* > svg`, which will be every tag except the root html tag.  Hope that helps.  Otherwise, you'll need to look up namespaces and how they are used.